# Can you use appendChild to add an element to a div that had a dynamically created id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic, appendchild

I am trying to add some `<p>` elements to a `div` using Javascript. The function loops to create a predetermined amount of these `div`s. My `id` for the `div` is created every time the function runs, and is just 'div' plus a number (e.g.: `div1`, `div2`, `div3`, etc.)

Here is my code:

```
var divNum = 'div';

function myFunction () {
    var divTag = document.createElement("div");
    divTag.id = "div";
    divTag.className ="info";        
    document.body.appendChild(divTag);
    var idXX = divNum;
    $('#div').attr('id',idXX);

    var text = document.createElement("p");
    text.id = "1";
    text.className ="text1-2"; 
    text.innerHTML = "A";
    *"PROBLEM HERE"*.appendChild(text);

    divNum = divNum + 1;
 }
```

My question is, can you do something to where it says `*"PROBLEM HERE"*` that makes it append a `div` with `id` equal to my var `idXX`?

Comment: Why not just use `divTag` in place of `*"PROBLEM HERE"*`?

Comment: Why are you mixing jQuery and DOM? Pick one and stick with it.

Comment: Also HTML4 does not support ids as integers.

Comment: As someone already mentioned, your code can be [much smaller](http://jsfiddle.net/5DEBk/4/) (simplified and HTML5 valid).

Answer (score 2):

Just use `divTag`.

That line would look like this:

```
divTag.appendChild(text);
```

Answer (score 2):

I may be misunderstanding the question, but it seems to me that the "PROBLEM HERE" line should just be this:

```
$('#'+idXX).append(text); // literally doing what you asked
```

Or simply this:

```
divTag.appendChild(text); // better approach since it doesn't have to go look for it.
```

Also, why do you create the div and then change its ID? Also, `divNum` is initialized as `"div"`, not `0` like is presumably intended...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jQuery and not mix it with base javascript:

```
var divNum = 'div';

function myFunction () {
    var divTag = $("<div>").
        .attr("id", divNum)
        .addClass("info");        
        .appendTo($("body"));
    $("<p>")
        .attr("id", "1")
        .addClass("test1-2")
        .html("A")
        .appendTo(divTag);

    divNum = divNum + 1;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your using jQuery to set the attribute id.

```
$('#div').attr('id',idXX);
```

You should be able to do everything in jQuery

```
var divNum = 0;
function myFunction() {
    var _p = $('<p>').text('A').addClass('text-1-2')
    $('<div>').attr({'id':'div'.concat(++divNum)}).addClass('info').html(_p).appendTo('body');
}
```